# tfs2010 on VMWare

Tags: vmware

We're thinking of running our TFS 2010 application tier on a virtual machine using VMWare.

We are a tiny shop (4 devs) and like the ability to upsize the power later.  Data would probably reside on a real server.

Hive mind: Please, tell me if this is a moronic idea.

Comment: why to close vote? Thought it was an interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the Microsoft recommendation is going to be here (although, I'm sure they'd suggest Hyper-V over VMWare at the very least).

That being said, I run TFS2010 in a lab environment with both TFS 2010 and the database within a VirtualPC instance (under Windows Server 2003).  It works, and for the type of work that I'm doing, it works pretty well.

Given what you're asking, I think a VM for the application tier should be fine.  I'm generally not a fan of virtualizing database servers, so I would stick with a separate machine that can be used for your data tier.

If you do wind up virtualizing the data tier, I would still strongly recommend tying it to a physical disk instead of a virtual HD.

Answer (score 1):

Our development shop actually runs TFS 2010 on a VMWare.  Database and everything.  So far we have not encountered any problems, though I have read that it is possible to have some problems with SQL server on a VM.  However, this is not our long term solution as well. This was done so we could get up and running without delay.  As long as you are backing up your data I think this is a good short term solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that in order to do both TFS tiers on a single server, you'll need to allocate at least 2GB, or you won't even be able to install.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it, data and everything.

For low-performance stuff, I even run [OMG] Oracle on VMs.